# PHP mail() SMTP server response: 452 4.3.1 Out of memory on Windows server

Tags: php, email, smtp

I'm trying to send mail on a shared server. my error page is

```
 <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mail() [<a href='function.mail'>function.mail</a>]: SMTP server response: 452 4.3.1 Out of memory in <b>D:\hshome\......\form.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />
email didnt send
<META HTTP-EQUIV ="Refresh" CONTENT =" 1; URL= Thank.html" />
```

this is the form.php

```
<?php 
include ("config.php");   
$mail_check=true; 
if(trim($_POST["name"])=="") 
    $mail_check=false; 
if(trim($_POST["email"])=="") 
    $mail_check=false; 
if(trim($_POST["subject"])=="") 
    $mail_check=false; 

if($mail_check){ 
    $to=$config["email"]; 
    $subject = $_POST["subject"]; 
    $message = '<html><head><title>$lang["newemailarriveed"]</title></head><body> 
    test
    </body></html>'; 
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= 'From: '.$_POST["name"].' <'.$_POST["email"].'>' . "\r\n"; 

    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){ 
        echo $lang["success"]; 
    } 
    else{ 
        echo $lang["eror1"]; 
    } 
}else{ 
    echo $lang["eror2"]; 
} 
?>
```

while `config.php` is

```
<?php 
// ServCombina
// Contact Form By TalGarty 
    $config = Array( 
        "email" => "info@example.com", 
        );         

    $lang = Array( 
        "newemailarriveed" => "new mail", 
        "newemailfrom" => "from", 
        "info" => "detail", 
        "fullname" => "name", 
        "iemail" => "email", 
        "phone" => "phone", 
        "success" => "success", 
        "eror1" => "email didnt send", 
        "eror2" => "one or more of the fields are empty", 
        );         
?>
```

*This is on windows shared server

I have to say that I dont know much php, I tried to send email through `asp.net` and it worked, however I cant move to `asp.net`m I have to stay in `php`.

in `asp.net` the following code works:

```
String s_name = "", s_email = "", s_phone = "";
if (name != null && name.Text != null) { s_name = name.Text; }    
if (email != null && email.Text != null) { s_email = email.Text; }
if (phone != null && phone.Text != null) { s_phone = phone.Text; }

MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.To.Add("example@example.com");
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("info@example.com");
mailMessage.Subject = "test";
mailMessage.Body = @"<!DOCTYPE html> "+
                    "<html  xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head><title>new email</title></head><body> " +
                    "test" +
                    "</body></html>"; 
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("mail.example.com");
smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
Response.Redirect("~/aaa/Thank.html");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Add at the top of the file this lines:

```
   ini_set('SMTP','mail.example.com');
   ini_set('sendmail_from','info@example.com');
```

The `ini_set('memory_limit','32M');` didnt help so I didnt put it in the file

Comment: Your server was Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your php.ini and change the memory_limit to whatever you need. For eg.
memory_limit = 32M

- You will require access to make changes to php.ini on the system. This change is global and will be used by all php scripts running on the system. Once you change this value, you will need to restart the web server in order for it to become active.
  Keep in mind that this limit has its logic and don’t increase it artificially, as poorly written php scripts might overkill your system without proper limits.
  Note: if you know what you are doing and want to remove the memory limit, you would set this value to -1.
- Changing memory_limit using .htaccess for a single folder/vhost
  Changing the global memory_limit might not be a good idea, and you might be better changing this only inside one folder (normally one application or virtual host) that needs this value changed for its functionality. To do this you have to add to the respective location .htaccess something like: php_value memory_limit 64M

**EDIT**

If your server is shared,  There's a way to increase to amount of memory allowed to PHP right in your script. On top of your file put the below code.

```
ini_set('memory_limit','32M');
```

The above code will increase the maximum amount of memory available to PHP to 32 MB. Again, the setting is only adjusted for the running script.

Comment: I store the site in shared server, just create a `php.ini` file and store it in the site root?

Comment: see the updated answer. include that code on top of the file where actually you execute mail() function. The setting is only adjusted for that execution period.

Comment: I've putted that line above `include ("config.php");` (also tried below that line) and still got `out of memory`.

Comment: Increase the memory limit like 256M

Comment: Solution I given here was for Linux Server. There is a slight difference in the mail processing in windows & Linux server. On IIS servers, You're required to specify SMTP server & related details..:)